# How to set fixed margins on Excel VBA code (PDF is printing in 2 pages instead of 1)

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have an Excel file which has a button "Generate PDF" that runs a macro to print a certain sheet (lets call it "QUOTE") into a PDF. This sheet is shown to be well limited in margins and in my computer the created PDF has the perfect structure: everything is well included in 1 page. However, in some other computers, when the PDF is created, everything does not fit into 1 page and a 2nd page is created with a bit of content. Here is the code (including the attempts to fix this problem by limiting the margins):

```
Sub Excel_Export_Proposal()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsCOTIZACION As Worksheet
Dim Proposalname As String
Dim iVis As XlSheetVisibility
Dim xlName As Excel.Name
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim myRange As String

Set wsQUOTE = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QUOTE")

FolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"


Proposalname = "Quote for " & CStr(Range("B2").Value)

wsQUOTE.PageSetup.PrintArea = myRange
With wsQUOTE.PageSetup
.FitToPagesTall = 1
.FitToPagesWide = False
.Zoom = False
.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
.RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.4)
.BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
.TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)


End With

'Proposal
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
wb.Unprotect
With wsQUOTE
iVis = .Visible
.Visible = xlSheetVisible
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                     Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Proposalname & ".pdf", _
                     Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                     IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                     IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
                     OpenAfterPublish:=True


.Visible = iVis

wsQUOTE.Activate


End With



wb.Protect 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Can somebody help me fixing this problem? I would like that the sheet would we printed perfectly regardless of the computer or software in which is generated...

Comment: Is the worksheet's page setup already set to be "Fit to 1 pages wide by 1 tall"?  Sorry, I only scrolled down to where you are doing the print - I didn't see that you are changing it to that after you print it.  Why don't you set it to 1 page tall **before** you print it?

Comment: Yes, Tall=1 and Wide=False, like its shown on the code

Comment: Try doing that **before** you print to the PDF file.

Comment: I will try, thank you!

Comment: Still not working.... I really don't understand why in my computer works and not on the others

Comment: Are you testing it all on the same version of Excel, Adobe and Windows?

Comment: The idea is that it should have the same output regardless of version of Excel, Windows or PDF viewer... but yes, Excel was the same version but Windows version and PDF viewers were different

Comment: One thing I notice, off the top of my head, is that you aren't setting your variable `myRange`, which defines the print area. Try defining it and see if it has an impact.

Comment: You mean select the cells that are included in the range? Isn't it done with the command wsQUOTE.PageSetup.PrintArea = myRange?

Answer (score 6):

In order to have the procedure `Excel_Export_Proposal` including the `PrintingArea` in one page always the following adjustments should be applied:

1. Set the printing area correctly:
   This line sets the printing area:   `wsQUOTE.PageSetup.PrintArea = myRange`
   However no value is assigned to the variable `myRange` before this line, therefore the `PrintArea` is set to `""` which is equivalent to setting it to the entire `UsedRange` of the `wsQUOTE` sheet.
2. To ensure that the entire `PrintArea` is printed in one page the `FitToPagesTall` and `FitToPagesWide` must be set to 1
   Replace `.FitToPagesWide = False` with `.FitToPagesWide = 1`
   And remove `.Zoom = False` as it has not effect after setting `FitToPagesTall` and `FitToPagesWide` to 1
3. To ensure that the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method uses the print areas as defined in the target excel file set the `IgnorePrintAreas` parameter to `False`.
   Replace this line `IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _` with this line `IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _`

Below is the revised procedure:

```
    Sub Excel_Export_Proposal_Revised()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsQuote As Worksheet
    Dim myRange As String, Proposalname As String, FolderPath As String
    Dim iVis As XlSheetVisibility

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set wsQuote = wb.Sheets("QUOTE")
        FolderPath = wb.Path & "\"
        Proposalname = "Quote for " & wsQuote.Range("B2").Value2

        'Update myRange with the address of the range to be printed
        myRange = "$B$2:$O$58"  'Change as required

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        With wsQuote.PageSetup
            .PrintArea = myRange
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
            .FitToPagesWide = 1     'Set FitToPagesWide to 1
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.4)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        End With

        'Proposal
        wb.Unprotect
        With wsQuote
            iVis = .Visible
            .Visible = xlSheetVisible
            .Activate
            .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=FolderPath & Proposalname & ".pdf", _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
            .Visible = iVis
        End With
        wb.Protect

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End Sub
```

See following pages for additional information on the resources used:

[Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-exportasfixedformat-method-excel)
[PageSetup Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-object-excel)

Comment: Great example, working for me almost flawlessly. In my case, I had to use the `.Zoom` property. **Without the `.Zoom = False`, the `.FitToPages` properties did not work for me.** The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.fittopageswide) on `.FitToPagesWide` property also suggests usage of the `.Zoom = False`.